# Event is not logged on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase on my Android app.

I'm using this [package](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-firebase-analytics) for my react-native project. I don't get any errors when I'm using it. However, events are not logged. Any help with this? Thanks!

I'm implementing the code like:

```
Analytics.setUserId(user.uid)
Analytics.logEvent('view_item', {
        'item_id': 'login'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) (Firebase documentation), you can see that it's a custom event, the custom events not appear on control panel but you can see that in audiences and as a filters for firebase analytics. If you want that your event is showed in your control panel you need to use a general events, you can learn more about them [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event), when you use the *user properties* or *regular events* the firebase needs 24h hours to recompile information and show it on control panel. Tell me if I helps you! Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

When your code triggers a "view_item", it is supposed to "trigger" an existing event from the firebase analytics console.

So you need to create an event that will handle the "view_item" event in your code.
From the console in analytics, you need to create a new event named "view_item_trigger" for example add the following condition:
"if event_name is equal to 'view_item' ".

[image: New Event screen 1]
[image: New Event screen 2]

The view_item_trigger event will now appear in the debug view

Comment: @eric-wu thanks for the edit because I don't have enough reputation to directly insert picture in my post.